# difficult integral involving exponentials and error functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to prove that for any $r \geq 0$, we have:
$$
\int_0^r \frac{x\,e^{x^2} \mathrm{erf}(x)}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \left(e^{r^2}-1\right)
$$

Where $\mathrm{erf}(x) := \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t$ is the standard error function. Tried a bunch of things; mostly integration by parts and trig subsitutions, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, substitute $y := \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$:
$$ I(r) := \int_0^r \frac{x\,e^{x^2} \mathrm{erf}(x)}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x = -\int_r^0 e^{r^2-y^2} \mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt{r^2-y^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}y $$
Next, using the definition of $\mathrm{erf}$:
$$ I(r) = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi} e^{r^2} \int_0^r \int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} e^{-y^2} e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}y $$
This is a double integral over the following domain:
$$ \{(t,y) \in\mathbb R^2 | 0<t, 0<y, t^2+y^2<r^2\} $$
That is a quarter circle with radius $r$. Using polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
I(r) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi} e^{r^2} \int_0^r \int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} e^{-(t^2+y^2)}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi} e^{r^2} \int_0^r \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-\rho^2} \rho\,\mathrm{d}\varphi \,\mathrm{d}\rho \\
&= \sqrt\pi e^{r^2} \int_0^r e^{-\rho^2} \rho\,\mathrm{d}\rho
\end{align}
Lastly, substitute $ u := \rho^2 $:
\begin{align}
I(r) &= \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} e^{r^2} \int_0^{r^2} e^{-u} \,\mathrm{d}u\\
&= \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} e^{r^2} \left(1-e^{-r^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} \left(e^{r^2}-1\right)
\end{align}